# How can I create a empty file whose name begins with a dash?

Tags: command-line, parameter, options

How can we create a empty file with the unix name `-stuff`.
It means the name start with `-`. I tried with `touch -stuff` but it didn't work.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

In general, most utilities have options that begin with `-`. Most of those utilities have a feature that allows you to specify an argument that is not an option by supplying the special option `--`.  For those utilities, `--` means that no further arguments are options. So in your case, you can use `touch -- -stuff`.

For more information about general conventions that many utilities follow, see [Section 12: "Utility Conventions"](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap12.html) of the [Base Definitions Volume](http://www.unix.org/version4/xbd_contents.html) of the [Single Unix Specification](http://www.unix.org/version4/).

Another way to create an empty file is by using the shell's redirection operator like so: `> -stuff`.

Comment: it means I can write like this touch --stuff

Comment: @Elham-abbasi, no; `--` must be its own separate argument, separated from the preceding and following arguments by the internal field separator (usually a space).

Comment: The IFS does not apply to the delimiter between positional  parameters. Rather, as per `man bash`... *IFS is The Internal Field Separator that is used for word splitting after expansion and to split lines into words with the read builtin command.  The default value is '<space><tab><newline>'.*  eg. `IFS=+; var1="a b c"; var2="a+b+c"; set $var1 $var2; echo "$@"; echo $1l; echo $2; echo $3; echo $4` .. for more, see [Advanced Bash-Scripting Guide -$IFS and whitespace](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/internalvariables.html)

Comment: @fered Nice! I tried it, and sure enough: it doesn't affect it. Here is `$IFS` in SUS: http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_05

So I went looking for documentation about what does affect arguments, and found this: http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_03 . A `<blank>` character is what separates tokens from each other. On the same page, you find that it is defined by the locale and can be changed by `$LC_CTYPE`.

Answer (score 15):

Also

```
touch ./-stuff
```

What happens here: for "usual" filenames the current directory (`./`) is implied and thus unnecessary. However, we can explicitly specify it with `./` (it's just redundant in normal cases); this way, the argument won't start with `-` and won't be parsed as an option, but as a filename.

Answer (score 4):

You can also use:

```
echo -n > -stuff
```

Comment: `echo -n` is not portable, you might end with a file containing "-n". Better to avoid running any command and just keep the redirection which creates (or empties) the target file.

Comment: @jlliagre.. Interesting, thanks... Some info on this point can be found here: [echo: APPLICATION USAGE](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/echo.html)

Answer (score 2):

As your question relates specifically to creating an **empty** file, be aware that `touch` is primarily intended to "touch" the timestamp of a file.
A secondary aspect of `touch` is that it will create an empty file if the named file doesn't exist.
This, of course, means that it will *not* always create an empty file.

To be certain that you end up with an empty file, you can use the `>` redirection opera1tor (as mentioned in other answers), or `cp -- /dev/null -a`

`touch` allow for creating (or just modifying the timestamp) of many files at once.
`>` and `cp` can only handle one file at a time..

Comment: `cp -- /dev/null -a` is overkill, `: > -a` or even `> -a` are sufficient.